# I have JavaLauncher on my Mac instead of Jar Launcher, and. jar files won't work

Tags: macos, java

I don't have Jar Launcher on my Mac Pro late 2013, Monterey 12.2.1 in /System/Library/CoreServices. I instead have JavaLauncher, and .jar files won't launch.

I could not find a solution to this. How do I fix this?

[image: This is a screenshot of my CoreServices folder.]

Comment: Have you installed Java from the Oracle site?

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, I have. I also have java update 333 installed.

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/java --version` show?

Comment: @mmmmmm I put `/usr/bin/java --version` in Finder, and no results showed up. However, `/usr/bin/java` does exist.

Comment: Ah I meant in Terminal.app

Comment: @mmmmmm This shows up when I type `/usr/bin/java --version` into Terminal.

`java 10.0.2 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)`

Comment: Do your jrs work if you run the from the command line?

Comment: @mmmmmm I ran these commands in Terminal. `sudo chmod +x /Users/Adam/Downloads/filename.jar` and `java -jar /Users/Adam/Downloads/filename.jar` This is the result. `Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Launcher
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Launcher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 54.0`

Comment: So try a newerjava

Comment: I already have the latest Java version installed

Comment: Java 10 is not the latest 19 is now out but 18 is the stable version

Comment: @mmmmmm I have downloaded and installed Java 18; `java 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)` shows up when I type `/usr/bin/java --version` into Terminal. However, when I try to run the file, an application shows up on the application bar at the bottom with the icon of a folder, and nothing shows up; and nothing is on the toolbar besides "java"

Comment: That might be a problem with the app - try another simple jar,